# How can you animate time?

Tags: animation

I've tried animating the ["Time Remapping" settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Output#Dimensions), but get the "property cannot be animated" message. Is there a way to animate the time of a scene?

Comment: @gandalf3, Well that's approaching [feature-request/bug-report](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/) territory. You should have (still can) [rollback/edit](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) the question if the changes were not beneficial. As it stands this is a duplicate and can/will be merged.