# I'd like to speed up an animation, Changing FPS doesn't do anything

Tags: animation, rigging

When I try to edit my FPS in my animation, it doesn't affect anything. The animation is very slow and I'd like to speed it up. If you need any files or such to help please ask! BTW: This happened when I started Blender, I didn't change anything.  I just rigged a model and animated it.

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41788/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-slow-down-the-preview-playback-of-an-animation-in-the/41797#41797 and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/how-to-stretch-120-seconds-of-animation-over-270-seconds/5056#5056 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/how-can-you-animate-time and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Comment: also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-speed-duration-for-animation/49587#49587

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is just your animation speed in the viewport, your computer might be lagging. You can fix this by changing your **Playback Sync** setting from *No Sync* to *Frame Dropping* at the bottom of your screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the frame rate as shown below:

[image]